# Add custom fields after post/page title

Tags: functions, custom-field, hooks, post-meta

I am using the Headway theme, and I need to add custom field code to page & posttitles. This is what I need to be able to do.

[example http://www.marbiedesign.nl/_img/customfield.jpg](http://www.marbiedesign.nl/_img/customfield.jpg) [edit:image has been deleted]

The red button will be added through a custom field. It needs to be shown inline with the title. I have worked out I can do this using the `headway_after_entry_title` hook, but I can't seem to get the code right to retrieve the custom fields. I got this far :

```
//Add custom field image after entry title 
function title_btn() {
    echo '<div class="title-btn">[custom field code to go here]</div>';
} 
add_action('headway_after_entry_title', 'title_btn');
```

and the outcome should be:

```
<a href="xxx"><img src="xxx"></a>
```

where the xxx is the custom field url code

Hope anybody can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the [`get_post_meta()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_meta/) function to retrieve those data.

So basically, you'd write a function in your functions.php file (or in a custom plugin - take "Hello Dolly" as example) and hook it.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: (#66495) »kaiser« Headway Title Button */
function wpse66495_headway_title_button()
{
    return printf(
         '<div class="title-btn"><a href="%s" alt="%s"><img src="%s /></a></div>'
        ,get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_key_link_url', true )
        ,get_the_title()
        ,get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_key_thumb_url', true )
    );
}
add_action( 'headway_after_entry_title', 'wpse66495_headway_title_button' );
```

Comment: how can I get my custom fields in here like this:

    <a href="customfield1"><img src="customfield2"></a>

both customfields are urls

Comment: See Update and _read_ the code. You'll see where to enter those meta keys.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! would it be possible to edit this function so it won't show if the fields are empty? At the moment it takes up a lot of blank space.

Comment: Check all the `isset()`, `empty()`, etc. stuff on php.net